# Why does Word 2007 add hundreds of pages when I save my document as a pdf?

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have a 34 page .docx document with a table of contents and many section breaks. When I go to save it as a PDF, Word chops up the content into 311 pages, putting a little bit from each normal page into the header section of the 311 pages. It does this both on my Word copy of the doucment and on my newly created PDF.

I've tried several converters and they all make 300 page pdfs. I know that there must be some marker in my word doc that tells the PDF makers to interpret it this way, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

[DoPdf](http://www.dopdf.com/download.php) is the best tool I used ever and there is no problem with no. of pages when I convert by it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to try diagnose this is trial and error. Try only converting the first few pages and see if this happens. Then try removing parts of the document until the problem goes away. If it remains with only a very small part of the document then maybe something's wrong with your Word, try a different machine.